# How does Python manage sys.modules?

Tags: python, module, python-import

I'm wondering about the contents of the `sys.modules` dictionary. For example, when I import the `compiler`package:

```
>>> import compiler
>>> for k in sys.modules:
...     if k == 'compiler' or k.startswith('compiler.'):
...             print k
...
compiler.sys
compiler.ast
compiler.token
compiler
compiler.consts
compiler.warnings
compiler.transformer
compiler.struct
compiler.parser
compiler.symbol
compiler.imp
compiler.visitor
compiler.cStringIO
compiler.os
compiler.compiler
compiler.syntax
compiler.future
compiler.dis
compiler.pycodegen
compiler.misc
compiler.pyassem
compiler.types
compiler.symbols
compiler.marshal
```

Why are there entries like `compiler.warnings` and `compiler.marshal`? They are not part of the `compiler` package nor actually attributes of the module:

```
>>> for k in sys.modules:
...     if k.startswith('compiler.') and hasattr(compiler, k.split('.')[1]):
...             print k
...
compiler.ast
compiler.consts
compiler.warnings
compiler.transformer
compiler.visitor
compiler.syntax
compiler.future
compiler.pycodegen
compiler.misc
compiler.pyassem
compiler.symbols
```

And the package contents are:

[image: Windows explorer showing the contents of the compiler package]

Why are the "extra items" in the `sys.modules` dictionary and what are they for? Modules like `marshal` are not part of the `compiler` package but are prefixed with `'compiler.'` and I don't see why. Additionally, there's an entry for the `marshal` module in `sys.modules` after importing the *compiler* package.

```
sys.modules['marshal']
<module 'marshal' (built-in)>
```

*Note: I picked the marshal randomly, it serves as a general replacement for any module.*

Comment: Interesting indeed; the extra modules are created as you import modules in the `compiler` package, and always have `None` as their value. Each of the 'extra' modules is something that is used by the `compiler` package.

Comment: If you read `.../Python/Lib/compiler/__init__.py` you'll see that it `imports` several other modules in the `compiler` package which in turn import other modules -- for example `pycodegen` `imports` `marshal`.

Comment: @martineau: Sure, but that does (at least for me) not clarify why the imported module is additionally to its usual entry stored as `importing_module.imported_module` in `sys.modules`.

Comment: Which version of Python? Could it have something to do with the `__future__.absolute_import` feature?